# Export to CSV button outside chart using Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

As show in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sajb/Afstw/), i have a export button outside the chart.On click of this i need to export the data to CSV.

It works fine if i add export button inside the context menu.
But if button is outside what should i do.

```
   Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
       text: 'Download CSV',
       onclick: function () {
            Highcharts.post('http://www.highcharts.com/studies/csv-export/csv.php', {
            csv: this.getCSV()
       });
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up your button click handler like so:

```
    $('#getcsv').click(function () {
       Highcharts.post('http://www.highcharts.com/studies/csv-export/csv.php', {
           csv: $('#container').highcharts().getCSV()
       });
    });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SUcK7/).